# Como bloquear o botão voltar (aquela setinha que fica no hardware)?

Tags: android

Preciso bloquear aquela seta para que o usuário não volte, alguém sabe como? Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Basta criar o método onBackPressed e não charmar o super dele, deixando apenas em branco o corpo da função. Ai toda vez que o usuario pressionar o botão voltar, não vai acontecer nada.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // não chame o super desse método
}
```

Obs.: esse método só deve ser escrito na `Activity`.

Comment: obrigado, é isso mesmo que eu precisava!